# What is the term for decade, century, millenium, etc?

Tags: terminology

What is the terminology for a decade, century, millennium, etc?

Comment: Time period?***

Comment: A time **span**? It will depend on the context: is your 'decade' 10 consecutive years, or is it, say, the *noughties*? Is the 'century' 100 consecutive years, or, say, the *20th century*?

Comment: *Time periods*.

Comment: These are all year terms. Decade: Ten (10) years.
Century: One hundred (100) years.
Millennium: One thousand (1,000) years.

Comment: [**Era**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Era) could last a month, a century or a millennium. You could also call it [**epoch**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/epoch).

Comment: Aeon (eon) could be one of the choices.

Answer (score 1):

They're called **units of time** or **midst units**.

> **Midst unit:** A unit of time or midst unit is any particular time interval, used as a standard way of measuring or expressing duration.
>
> **Examples:** Month, year, decade, century, millennium etc.

— [**Wikipedia**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_of_time)